# Using Instruments to Know What Activity Occurs at a Given Time

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments

As the Instruments trace below shows, I have some regular plunges in my Physical Free Memory. At the same time the percent user load rises. Allocations remains steady, but the tabular listings show some operations have a high peak to average ratio.

[image]

I don't understand enough about Instruments to identify what activity is happening at the time the free memory plunges. I can look at Time Profiler in the detail pane, but this appears to be cumulative, from the beginning. I would like to see what's happening over a the narrow window of time where memory use goes up.

Also, I don't understand why the tack for the Time Profiler shows no activity during these times when memory use goes up, but the Activity Monitor shows high activity.

Would someone provide some guidance on how to interpret this and how to get more out of it so I can understand the memory using problem? Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen when interacting with your app in a certain way?

Comment: By the way, my app is just sitting idle during this trace, immediately after start up. There is no user interaction going on, and it appears to have reach equilibrium with all startup code having run completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click the button below the tracks ("Statistics"?) and choose "Objects List".
- Order the table by Timestamp.
- Zoom in on the track for the region you want to analyze.
- Click in the track/graph -- Instruments will jump to that time.

You may also benefit by using Heapshot Analysis.

Comment: Okay, I found that in the allocations track. I would like to see Objective-C only, but that option is not available. I think this might be the answer to my question. I'll look it over more carefully tonight. I do see a lot of Core Location calls, but I am also seeing these calls at times when memory is not low. I guess I should look for something unique to that low-memory time frame and look into it.

Comment: I have a follow up question here, if you have a chance to look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496068/using-instruments-for-tracking-down-excessive-memory-use